# Remove all elements from a List after and before a particular index

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, java-8, indexof

Is there any way in Java to remove ALL elements from a List except given index ? Lets supose that we have :

```
List<String> foo = new ArrayList<>();
foo.add("foo0");
foo.add("foo1");
foo.add("foo2");
foo.add("foo3");
foo.add("foo4");
```

And I want to preserve ONLY the element with index 2 (foo2) , all the other Strings must be removed .

I need a method like : given a List of strings and a given index , remove all elements of that list before and after the index
How can I achieve this goal ?

Cheers

Comment: Do you have to keep the same `List` instance assigned to `foo`? Do you have duplicates in the list?

Comment: Isn't it easier just to get that element and drop the list?

Comment: yes and I dont have any duplicates , i need a method that removes all elements form a given list , given an index

Comment: Although the question asks for the first element, the answers are index-parametrized here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3099527/4636715 It may help.

Comment: in my opinion, this is bad programming, you should keep your list immutable, if you need a list that only contains what you need, then create a new one(with whatever logic) then replace the old one

Comment: `Collections.swap(foo, 0, 2); foo.subList(1, foo.size()).clear();`

Comment: Do you need more or is your question answered?

Comment: My question is answered , thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
foo.subList(0, 2).clear(); // after execution of that line Your index 2 object  is on index 0.
foo.subList(1, foo.size()).clear();
```

Now your list `foo` contain only one element which was initially at index 2.

Updated :

```
public void RemoveAllExceptIndex(List<String> foo,int index) {
    foo.subList(0, index).clear();
    foo.subList(1, foo.size()).clear();
}
```

Comment: And how can I transform that into a method  like : given a List of strings and a given index , remove all elements of that list before and after the index?

Comment: This is the right idea if the list needs to be edited in place.  I applaud you @KhalidShah for trying to answer the OPs question.  But this code isn't right as is.  Did you actually try it?  Just create a list with a few elements in it and try it, and you'll see that it doesn't do what is expected.

Comment: I realized I could edit your answer instead of posting a community alternative.  i did that.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
Arrays.asList(foo.get(2));
```

or

```
Collections.singletonList(foo.get(2))
```

So as a method you can implement:

```
// Returns a fixed-size list ..
public List<String> subList(List<String> list, int index) {
    return Arrays.asList(list.get(index));
}
```

or

```
public List<String> subList(List<String> list, int index) {
        return Collections.singletonList(list.get(index));
    }
```

or

```
public List<String> subList(List<String> list, int index) {
    return list.subList(index, ++index);
}
```

Comment: but be aware that size of new list cannot be changed - *"Returns a fixed-size list ..."*

Comment: Why go the array detour. Just use `Collections.singletonList(…)`

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
foo = foo.subList(2, 3);
```

Transformed into a method, it would be like:

```
public List<String> subList(List<String> list, int index)
{
    return list.subList(index, index + 1);
}
```

Or if you prefer not to reassign the original list:

```
public void subList(List<String> list, int index)
{
  String elm;
  elm = list.get(index);
  list.clear();
  list.add(elm);
}
```

Comment: And how can I transform that into a method like : given a List of strings and a given index , remove all elements of that list before and after the index?

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList(foo.get(2));
// you can keep foo list or empty it later.
```

Comment: but be aware that the size of new list cannot be changed - *"Returns a fixed-size list ..."*

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to keep the old list.

```java
foo.retainAll(Collections.singleton(foo.get(2)));
```

Comment: This will keep all occurrences of the specified value rather than one. Besides that, use `Collections.singleton(…)` to get a single element set without the need to create an array. And there’s one `)` missing.

Comment: Thanks for the `Collections.singleton()` tip. Did not know about.

Answer (score 0):

**In Java-8 you can do like below:**

```
    List<String> li = Arrays.asList("foo0", "foo1", "foo2", "foo3");
    List<String> finalList = li.stream().filter(s -> s.compareTo("foo2") == 0).findAny() ;
    System.out.println(finalList);
```

> **List**->**Stream**->**Apply_Filter**->**Collect_to_new_List**

`s.compareTo("foo2") == 0` , ensures that only `foo2` pass the `filter()`.

Comment: This will keep all occurrences of the specified value rather than the element at a specified index. Besides that, there is no reason to use `s.compareTo("foo2") == 0` instead of a straight-forward `s.equals("foo2")`.

Comment: `findfirst()` would be apt at this place? Since op wants the first occurance.. @holger , right??

Comment: The OP specifically said that the index is given, but for `String` elements it wouldn’t matter which of the equal strings you keep so `findAny()` would do.

Comment: @holger, thanks man for recommendations. I am on cab now from my office so cant edit answer.